# How do I deploy an app to my Ubuntu phone with the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, installed the Ubuntu SDK, and created an app from the "HTML5 App" template. I am able to create emulators in the devices tab (although I haven't managed to run them successfully; but that's another question), but my Ubuntu phone, which is plugged in via USB, does not appear, and I can't see any way to add it. I have pressed refresh, and the phone is unlocked.

[image: Devices tab]

Comment: And the developer mode is activated on the phone?

Comment: Ah, I thought something like that would be necessary, but couldn't find any mention of it on the SDK help.  It would be helpful if this page mentioned it: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/sdk/tutorials/running-apps-from-the-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

The phone must be in developer mode, which can be turned on through

**System Settings > About this phone > Developer mode**

Comment: And you must have unlocked the screen of the device